# Question about trace class operators

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, trace

Let $\cal{H}$ be a Hilbert space, $T$ a bounded linear operator on $\cal{H}$, $S$ a trace class operator, then can one verify that
$$|Tr(TS)|\leq\|T\|\cdot|Tr(S)|?$$

Comment: Are you perhaps confusing the absolute value of the trace of a trace operator with the trace norm?  They are completely different things in general.  The inequality you state holds true if you replase $|Tr(TS)|$ with $\|TS\|_{tr}$ where the last norm is the trace norm.  For instance, you can see P. Lax, Functional Analysis, Ch. 30 Section 2, Thm 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Let
$$
S=\begin{bmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{bmatrix},\ \ T=\begin{bmatrix}0&0\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Then
$$
\text{Tr}(TS)=1,\ \ \text{ and } \|T\|\,|\text{Tr}(S)|=0.
$$

Answer (score 2):

It is correct for positive operators, for more information see  Gohberg, Krein, Introduction to the Theoryof Linear Non-Self-Adjoint
Operators in Hilbert Space page 27